# Using split environment in amsbook class causes \widetilde to come out too wide in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, accents, amsbook

I ran into the following very weird thing with the **amsbook** class:

After having used the **split** environment, a **\widetilde** in any subsequent chapter or section heading will come out looking wrong in the table of contents (but not in the actual text).

I haven't tried other environments systematically, but for example **align*** doesn't trigger this, as can be seen from the example below. Neither does this occur with the ordinary **book** document class (importing the **amsmath** package by hand).

Example:

```
\documentclass{amsbook}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Symbols $A$ and $\widetilde{A}$}
\begin{align*}
  a &= b \\
  c &= d
\end{align*}

\chapter{Symbols $B$ and $\widetilde{B}$}
\begin{equation*}
  \begin{split}
    a &= b \\
    c &= d
  \end{split}
\end{equation*}

\chapter{Symbols $C$ and $\widetilde{C}$}

\end{document}
```

Running this through pdflatex, I get a file whose table of contents looks like this:
[image: Strange t.o.c.]

As mentioned, the \widetilde{C} looks perfectly normal in the chapter heading in the text.

The .toc file looks as follows:

```
\contentsline {chapter}{\tocchapter {Chapter}{1}{Symbols $A$ and $\setbox \z@ \hbox {\frozen@everymath \@emptytoks \mathsurround \z@ $\textstyle A$}\mathaccent "0365{A}$}}{3}
\contentsline {chapter}{\tocchapter {Chapter}{2}{Symbols $B$ and $\setbox \z@ \hbox {\frozen@everymath \@emptytoks \mathsurround \z@ $\textstyle B$}\mathaccent "0365{B}$}}{5}
\contentsline {chapter}{\tocchapter {Chapter}{3}{Symbols $C$ and $\setbox \z@ \hbox {\frozen@everymath \@emptytoks \mathsurround \z@ $\textstyle C$}\mathaccent "055D{C}$}}{7}
```

Apparently the difference is that, after using split, the widetilde gets replaced in the .toc file by `\mathaccent "055D` instead of `\mathaccent "0365`. (What this actually means is way beyond my TeXnichal knowledge...)

**My question**:
Does anyone have any idea of what causes this, and if there is any workaround (other than hand-editing the .toc file to replace 055D by 0365)?

Comment: Embrace the `split` with braces `{ \begin{split} ...
  \end{split} }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fragile command in moving argument, use `\protect\widetilde` (the fact that the first ones sort of half work is an accident:-)

Comment: Ah, so easy... I tried putting in a \protect just after \chapter (since I saw that suggestion in some other question), but then the whole chapter heading disappeared from the TOC. I guess I should try to really understand the principles of how things work some day when I get the time and inspiration, but for now I will have to manage with Cargo Cult LaTeXing. :-) Thanks anyway!

Comment: @HansLundmark if you look in the toc you will see that `\protect` has prevented `widetilde` expanding so it gets written as itself and then the correct tilde can be chosen for the fonts in the toc when it is read back in.

Comment: I see. That makes sense!

Comment: Still, I can't help wondering what it is that triggers this behaviour under these particular surcumstances. I would never have expected an environment like "split" to have the side effect of somehow changing the internal state of LaTeX so that it behaves differently before and afterwards! But then again, I know painfully little about the inner workings of LaTeX...

Comment: @HansLundmark I could trace it but honestly it's not worth it; it is probably just random accident such as a scratch macro like `\@reserved@a` being empty or not. If you expand a fragile command while writing to a file then expansion happens but assignments such as def do not, so any tests of macros that were expected to have been defined (or in this case measuring the size of things) make the tests even though the assignment they are testing didn't happen, so basically you are lucky if what gets written out doesn't stop latex with a fatal error.

Comment: Well, I don't really expect anyone to trace this particular error in detail. But I was curious what kind of mechanism might be behind it, and this became a little clearer now. Thanks again! (Although regarding the word "lucky", I would probably have considered myself luckier if I *had* received a fatal error right from the beginning, instead of things working by accident first and then coming back to bite me later...) ;-)